# Doc File Creation Not Working In Linux For Adding Images

Tags: php

I am creating a doc file dynamically. Actually i converting html content to doc|docx files. Html content has some images in it. It was working fine and created well when i test in my local which is a windows system.

But when my code is pushed into my staging which is in LINUX. In that word doc is created but only text contents are added and images are not added in that doc. Please help me on this..

In head of file i am adding following code while creating doc file

```
<<<EOH
         <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
        xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
        xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

        <head>
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
        <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 9">
        <meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 9">
        <!--[if !mso]>
        <style>
        v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
        o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
        w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
        .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
        <title>$this->title</title>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
         <w:WordDocument>
          <w:View>Print</w:View>
          <w:DoNotHyphenateCaps/>
          <w:PunctuationKerning/>
          <w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridHorizontalSpacing>
          <w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>9.35 pt</w:DrawingGridVerticalSpacing>
         </w:WordDocument>
        </xml><![endif]-->
        <style>
        <!--
         /* Font Definitions */
        @font-face
            {font-family:Verdana;
            panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;
            mso-font-charset:0;
            mso-generic-font-family:swiss;
            mso-font-pitch:variable;
            mso-font-signature:536871559 0 0 0 415 0;}
         /* Style Definitions */
        p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
            {mso-style-parent:"";
            margin:0in;
            margin-bottom:.0001pt;
            mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
            font-size:7.5pt;
                mso-bidi-font-size:8.0pt;
            font-family:"Verdana";
            mso-fareast-font-family:"Verdana";}
        p.small
            {mso-style-parent:"";
            margin:0in;
            margin-bottom:.0001pt;
            mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
            font-size:1.0pt;
                mso-bidi-font-size:1.0pt;
            font-family:"Verdana";
            mso-fareast-font-family:"Verdana";}
        @page Section1
            {size:8.5in 11.0in;
            margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in;
            mso-header-margin:.5in;
            mso-footer-margin:.5in;
            mso-paper-source:0;}
        div.Section1
            {page:Section1;}
        -->
        </style>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
         <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1032">
          <o:colormenu v:ext="edit" strokecolor="none"/>
         </o:shapedefaults></xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
         <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
          <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1"/>
         </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
         $this->htmlHead
        </head>
        <body>
EOH;
```

Comment: So where exactly are these images? Let me guess, `$this->htmlHead`, which you haven't bothered to show us at all

Comment: Below these header content we have that images added in it... as <img src> after html tags..

Comment: May i know do i need to do ant specific change on my code or take care for linux server?